# Can't get CSS list-group-horizontal to fill container and be centered

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to get a `container` containing a `row` and then a `list-group-horizontal` group of items and ensure that it fills the entire HTML page horizontally, and is centered. Currently, these group items bunch to the left and do not fill the page horizontally until the screen size is very narrow, rescaling to lower width when the page is reduced in width.

Currently the result of the code is the following:

[image]

I want category 1, 2 and 3 to fill the page, and adjust when more categories are added.

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Shop Homepage HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

body {
    padding-top: 70px; /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}

.slide-image {
    width: 100%;
}

.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item {
 display: inline-block;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item {
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-left:-4px;
 margin-right: 0;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:first-child {
 border-top-right-radius:0;
 border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:last-child {
 border-top-right-radius:4px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:0;
}

.carousel-holder {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.carousel-control,
.item {
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.caption {
    height: 130px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.caption h4 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
}

.ratings {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #d17581;
}

.thumbnail {
    padding: 0;
}

.thumbnail .caption-full {
    padding: 9px;
    color: #333;
}

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Shop Homepage - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<!--    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/shop-homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/dropdown.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <!--    Support paging via http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">eBuy Platform</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="profile.html">Your Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <!--                       This should be dependent on your user type-->
                        <a href="mybids.html">Your Bids/Your Auctions</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <!--                       This should be depending on user type-->
                        <a href="#">Submit Auction</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html">Logout</a>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:50px">
                <p class="lead">Username</p>
                <div class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>


            <!--            End of row of categories-->
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">


        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for items" />
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                                <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                                        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="filter">Filter by</label>
                                                <select class="form-control">
                                                    <option value="0" selected>All Snippets</option>
                                                    <option value="1">Featured</option>
                                                    <option value="2">Most popular</option>
                                                    <option value="3">Top rated</option>
                                                    <option value="4">Most commented</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="contain">Author</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="contain">Contains the words</label>
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                                            </div>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <!--        Start listings of auctions-->
        <div class="col-md-9">

            <!--
            <div class="row carousel-holder" style="padding-top:50px">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <img class="slide-image" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
-->

            <div class="row" style="padding-top:50px">

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right">$24.99</h4>
                            <h4><a href="productpage.html">First Auction</a>
                                </h4>
                            <p>Description of product</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <p class="pull-right">15 reviews</p>
                            <p>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right">$64.99</h4>
                            <h4><a href="productpage.html">Second Auction</a>
                                </h4>
                            <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <p class="pull-right">12 reviews</p>
                            <p>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right">$74.99</h4>
                            <h4><a href="productpage.html">Third Auction</a>
                                </h4>
                            <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <p class="pull-right">31 reviews</p>
                            <p>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right">$84.99</h4>
                            <h4><a href="productpage.html">Fourth Auction</a>
                                </h4>
                            <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <p class="pull-right">6 reviews</p>
                            <p>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4 class="pull-right">$94.99</h4>
                            <h4><a href="productpage.html">Fifth Auction</a>
                                </h4>
                            <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ratings">
                            <p class="pull-right">18 reviews</p>
                            <p>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    To be filled out
                </div>
-->

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <div class="container">

        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: with what browser compatibility? Flexbox will do this easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>.Here where you have `<!--Start listings of auctions--> .col-md-9`, change to `.col-md-12`</strike>

**Update**:

Add to `.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item` this:

```
 width:33.3%;
 text-align:center
```

#### Snippet

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Shop Homepage HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

body {
  padding-top: 70px;
  /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}
.slide-image {
  width: 100%;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width:33.3%;
  text-align:center
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
.carousel-holder {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.carousel-control,
.item {
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.caption {
  height: 130px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.caption h4 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.thumbnail img {
  width: 100%;
}
.ratings {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: #d17581;
}
.thumbnail {
  padding: 0;
}
.thumbnail .caption-full {
  padding: 9px;
  color: #333;
}
footer {
  margin: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!--    Support paging via http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">eBuy Platform</a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
          <a href="profile.html">Your Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <!--This should be dependent on your user type-->
          <a href="mybids.html">Your Bids/Your Auctions</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <!-- This should be depending on user type-->
          <a href="#">Submit Auction</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:50px">
      <p class="lead">Username</p>
      <div class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End of row of categories-->
  </div>
</div>


<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="input-group" id="adv-search">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for items" />
          <div class="input-group-btn">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
              <div class="dropdown dropdown-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
                  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="filter">Filter by</label>
                      <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="0" selected>All Snippets</option>
                        <option value="1">Featured</option>
                        <option value="2">Most popular</option>
                        <option value="3">Top rated</option>
                        <option value="4">Most commented</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="contain">Author</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="contain">Contains the words</label>
                      <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<!-- Start listings of auctions-->
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row" style="padding-top:50px">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="pull-right">$24.99</h4>
            <h4><a href="productpage.html">First Auction</a>
                                </h4>
            <p>Description of product</p>
          </div>
          <div class="ratings">
            <p class="pull-right">15 reviews</p>
            <p>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="pull-right">$64.99</h4>
            <h4><a href="productpage.html">Second Auction</a></h4>
            <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="ratings">
            <p class="pull-right">12 reviews</p>
            <p>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="pull-right">$74.99</h4>
            <h4><a href="productpage.html">Third Auction</a>
                                </h4>
            <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="ratings">
            <p class="pull-right">31 reviews</p>
            <p>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="pull-right">$84.99</h4>
            <h4><a href="productpage.html">Fourth Auction</a>
                                </h4>
            <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="ratings">
            <p class="pull-right">6 reviews</p>
            <p>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h4 class="pull-right">$94.99</h4>
            <h4><a href="productpage.html">Fifth Auction</a>
                                </h4>
            <p>This is a short description. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="ratings">
            <p class="pull-right">18 reviews</p>
            <p>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
                    To be filled out
                </div>
-->

    </div>

  </div>


<!-- /.container -->

<div class="container">

  <hr>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: This didn't do anything unfortunately

Comment: It did to me when I changed in your site using dev tools, I'm gonna update my answer with a snippet.

Comment: Your code had a lot of issues in HTML, I tried to fixed some of them. see my snippet in my Updated answer. Hit Full Page link so you can see the desired effect.

Comment: this doesn't get the category 1, 2, 3 boxes (the filters) etc to be centered and fill the page horizontally e.g. there should be a row of 3 boxes spanning horizontally across the page on full screen.

Comment: AHHH my bad, I understood the boxes below those categories. give me a minute to update the answer